# Proportionally Resizing without extending to 100% width and height

Tags: javascript, html, css, resize, responsive

I've build an ad with an click tag. Everything works fine - the images are scaling proportionally but is there a way for the container not to fill 100% of width/height and still be scaling?

Preview:
https://craftads.de/hosting/stack_test5/

Wetransfer Code:
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/5b7b21ccd2a0f535cfcb22146ae5e41b20210823135155/edf6cd

I would like that only the visible part to be clickable.

Visual representation:

[This is what I would like to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8C8y.png)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: yes we can do that for sure can you just show some code

Comment: You can use viewport units ? `vh`and`vw` or just use percentages that are different than `100%`? :)

Comment: Some code please!

Comment: @sairaj The containers are using basically all: .gwd-page-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

Comment: I guess somehow you are attaching the clickEvent to that whole page, instead of just the content you want

Comment: Well yes, but the container is already set-up to 100% ... And I would like something like 500x1000 but scaling proportionally 1:2

Comment: This is the Code: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/5b7b21ccd2a0f535cfcb22146ae5e41b20210823135155/edf6cd

Comment: @MihaiTBut will it not be the same result? As I want to only the Content be clickable and not the whole screen?

Comment: @sairaj The content is set-up to 100% - I don't know how to scale it without the 100% - So if I attach the the clickTag onto the content it gets 100% as well. I posted an wetransfer link with the code for reference. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error I think I've found a solution:

```
html, body {
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
margin: 0px;
max-width: 50vh;
min-width: 500px;
min-height: 1000px;}
```

Does that make any sense haha?